# Expand the secondary text of a secondary_text of a TwoLineListItem in Python

Tags: python, kivymd

I am making a Python program using Kivymd. I've recently been trying to add more lines of text to an object that I'm using to create a "TwoLineListItem" list, however I can't find a way to expand the text so that all the text written to the secondary_text can be visible and expand according to the amount of text. I am using this line of code to create the object:

```
item = TwoLineListItem(text="Admin", secondary_text="This text can be big or small", secondary_font_style = "Caption")
```

This is an example of what the layout looks like so far:
[image: imagen de ejemplo1]